# Pagination in spring using JDBI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pagination, jdbi

I am creating an API where I want to implement pagination.
I need to fetch all the feedback and the result is around 5K. I am trying to implement pagination in the API.
I am using JDBI v3 in my project.
One of the solutions which I think of now is to use LIMIT and OFFSET in the SQL Query.

```
pageSize = 5  
pageNo = 1.
pageNo = pageSize * (pageNo - 1)  
SELECT * FROM feedback where product_id in (2,3,4,...) order by id ASC LIMIT pageSize OFFSET pageNo.
```

My API URL is "/product/feedback?pageNo=1&pageSize=5.
Is there any other approach that is more efficient?
Any input will be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are few potential downsides to that approach, but it really depends on the specifics of your domain. Here are a few articles I’d recommend:

- https://coderwall.com/p/lkcaag/pagination-you-re-probably-doing-it-wrong
- https://slack.engineering/evolving-api-pagination-at-slack/

Both cover the limit offset approach you have as an example.